# How to get route destination list of Global IP

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I select one global subnet and jump to detail, display route destination list with combo.
First, how to get route destination list and second, how to update modified info (routed destination & notes) using api?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### **To get route destination list:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch?objectMask=mask[resource(SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress) [id, ipAddress, hardware.fullyQualifiedDomainName, virtualGuest.fullyQualifiedDomainName, subnet[id, datacenter.longName, version, addressSpace], endpointSubnetCount]]

Method: POST

{  
   "parameters":[  
      "subnet.version:4 subnet.addressSpace:PUBLIC _objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress"
   ]
}
```

**Method**: [SoftLayer_Search::advancedSearch](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch)

---

### **To update the route destination**

You should route the global ip again, this will reemplace the past route:

**Method**: [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global::route](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/route)

Here a rest request for it:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/32585/route

Method: POST

{  
   "parameters":[  
      "173.193.77.174"
   ]
}
```

Anyway, if you want **To unroute the global ip address:**

**Method**: [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global::unroute](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/unroute)

---

### **To edit the notes**

You should do it in the Subnet, the following method will help with it:

**Method**: [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::editNote](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/editNote)

e.g:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/881127/editNote

Method: POST

{  
   "parameters":[  
      "Rcv test"
   ]
}
```

> Update

Using [SoftLayer API Client for Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java) the scripts should be like this:

### To get route destionation list:

```
package com.softlayer.api.GlobalIp;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Search;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.search.Result;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This script retrieves route destination list
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Search_Result
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetRouteDestination {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to get Route Destination
     */
    public GetRouteDestination() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Create client and Search Service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Search.Service searchService = Search.service(client);

        // Define a search terms
        String searchString = "subnet.version:4 subnet.addressSpace:PUBLIC _objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress";


        try {
            List<Result> result = searchService.advancedSearch(searchString);
            // Print Json
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetRouteDestination  method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetRouteDestination();
    }


}
```

---

### To update the route destination

```
package com.softlayer.api.GlobalIp;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.subnet.ipaddress.Global;
import com.softlayer.api.service.provisioning.version1.Transaction;

/**
 * This script creates a new transaction to modify a global IP route
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/route
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Version1_Transaction
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class Route {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Route
     */
    public Route() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Global IP identifier
        Long globalId = new Long(32583);

        // Create client and Search Service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Global.Service globalService = Global.service(client, globalId);

        // Define a search terms
        String newEndPointIpAddress = "169.53.15.61";

        try {
            Transaction result = globalService.route(newEndPointIpAddress);
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of Route method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Route();
    }


}
```

---

### To edit notes:

```
package com.softlayer.api.GlobalIp;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Subnet;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.subnet.ipaddress.Global;
import com.softlayer.api.service.provisioning.version1.Transaction;

/**
 * This script edits note for a subnet
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/editNote
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class EditNote {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to edit notes from subnet
     */
    public EditNote() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Subnet identifier
        Long subnetId = new Long(881127);

        // Create client and Search Service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Subnet.Service subnetService = Subnet.service(client, subnetId);

        // The note that you wish to add
        String note = "Java Client RcvTest";

        try {
            boolean result = subnetService.editNote(note);
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of EditNote method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EditNote();
    }


}
```